# Why is my account not Premium after adding funds to my Steam Wallet?

Tags: steam

I have added funds to my Steam account and used it to buy a game (but I have not added it to my library).

I also believe I have been on Steam for about 30 days, as I have been playing since the 1st of July and it is now August 1st.

Why is my account still not considered to be Premium?

Comment: Related: [How to know if your Steam account is premium?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119959/how-to-know-if-your-steam-account-is-premium)

Comment: Maybe you're talking about TF2? If you bought a game/added funds your Steam account should already be premium, so I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: Also, there may be a slight delay or something. How long has it been since you added funds?

Comment: If you have added $5+ to your Steam wallet, you should have premium access. If you don't, try logging out and then back in. If you don't have access within say 24 hours, I would contact Steam support. https://support.steampowered.com/

Comment: I think you need to activate the game.  If premium is there to force people to have 'skin in the game' for an account to be premium: then buying a game, adding it to your inventory, and trading it seems to bypass this and that is why you probably are not premium.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% certain about this, but I believe that you account only becomes premium when you add a game to your library.